# How can make or find 'timpani rolling' sound?

Tags: sound-design, sound, sample

I want to use sound like this.

Is there any free sound sample, or paid sample?
or some good VSTi?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest 5 ways,

**1. Find a Piece old enoguh that it has become Creative Commons and Take a recording of it.**

**2. Google the CC audio up**

**3. FM Synthesize it**

- Convert this Youtube video into an Audio file (You can't use this Audio file in you track if you are planning to release your track since the video is not creative common, But if you are not planning to release your track, I think it's not illegal to use this Audio file. But I'm not sure.)
- Inspect the Transient of a single Timpani hit. Observe its Spectral Properties using a Spectrogram in you DAW.
- If you're a pro go from scratch using an FM synth, else: Bring in a Tom sample and induce the properties you've observed of the Timpani using your favourite Synthesizer.

(I think FL Sytrus or FM8 will suffice for this. You can also you a simple Kick Drum VSTi or Wavetable Synthesizers too)

**4. There are a few YouTube videos that says "Synthesize Analog Timpani" Try them**

**5. Use MuseScore's Sounds (It is GNU Licensed and Users can Modify the Software or do anything to it)** And compared to Musescore 2, Musescore 3's update got an extreme leap in their samples' quality.